# Building a card widget [Flutter]

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to build my own card within flutter however I keep getting the error of child not being defined.

The type of card I am trying to build can be seen [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DYFykCCUMAA8KPA.jpg:large)

Is it also possible to link me to a tutorial that properly  explains when to use child and children as this seems to be my issue at this time.

My code can be seen below:

```
    List<Widget> cardlist = <Widget>[
  new Card(
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
          child: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: new AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
            radius: 100.0,
          ),
        )
      ],
      child: new Row(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: new AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
          radius: 100.0,
        ),
        child: new Text(
          'News Location',
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: new Image.asset(
        'images/lake.jpg',
        height: 240.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      child: new Text(
        'News Headline',
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      child: new Text(
        'News Summary',
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      child: new Row(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: new AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
          radius: 100.0,
        ),
        child: new Text(
          'News Source',
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        child: new Text(
          '12 hours ago',
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),

      ),
    ),
  )
];
```

Comment: can you quote the actual error (including line) ? This doesn't help much

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like what I have below, not sure it is exactly right but it should give you a starting point.  Basically you need to understand when to use child and when children, and the correct syntax.  just think about the widget you are using and if it could contain one (child) or more than one (children) child widgets, or look at the docs to see what it takes :)

```
body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Card(
              child: new Column(                
                children: [
                  new Row(
                    children: [
                      new CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: new AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
                        radius: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ]
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            ),
            new Card(
              child : new Row(
                children : [
                  new CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: new AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
                    radius: 100.0,
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    'News Location',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            ),
            new Card(
              child: new Column(                
                children: [
                  new Image.asset(
                    'images/lake.jpg',
                    height: 240.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    'News Headline',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    'News Summary',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    children : [
                      new CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: new AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
                        radius: 100.0,
                      ),
                      new Text(
                        'News Source',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Text(
                        '12 hours ago',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```